# Is creating runnables as a Spring component a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

It is the first time i use concurrency with Spring and i have a piece of code that makes concurrent calculations using Spring. Here is the code :

```
@Component
public class AppScheduler {

    //@Autowired DAOs or services.

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    private AbstractApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(VtmDispatcherConfig.class);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60 * 1000)
    //at rejection break the execution.
    public void appEntry() {
        //fetch some records from db 
        for (Record rec : records) {
            try {
                executeTransactionally(rec);
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    //Creates runnable tasks, makes some db operations and passes task to the thread pool
    private void executeTransactionally(Record rec) {
        ARunnableTask aRunnableTask = (ARunnableTask) context.getBean("aRunnableTask");
        aRunnableTask.setParameter(rec.param);
        //some db operations...
        tempTableExecutorPool.execute(aRunnableTask);
    }
}
```

Here a scheduled code fetchs records from db and with each record instantiates a runnable task and passes it to the thread pool executor. And my runnable task is here :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ARunnableTask implements Runnable {

    private String param;

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    private DAOOrService inject

    @Autowired
    public TempTableExecutorTask(DAOOrService inject) {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000));
        this.inject = inject;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //...
        executeTransactional();
        //...
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    @Transactional
    private void executeTransactional() {
        //some transactional processes
    }

    public void setParameter(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

}
```

and here is my question : Is it a good practice creating runnable tasks as a spring component and using @Transactional in a runnable?

If it is not a bad practice, is there a better way for creating runnable spring components than :

```
ARunnableTask aRunnableTask = (ARunnableTask) context.getBean("aRunnableTask");
aRunnableTask.setParameter(rec.param);
```